# Computing loglikelihood ratio using values in dict

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

First of, I have extracted some text from a file using the code below:

```
from collections import Counter

def n_gram_opcodes(source, n):
    source = open(source).read()
    OPCODES = set(["add","call","cmp","mov","jnz","jmp","jz","lea","pop","push",
    "retn","sub","test","xor"])

    source_words = source.split()
    opcodes = [w for w in source_words if w in OPCODES]

    return Counter(zip(*[opcodes[i:] for i in range(n)]))
```

The code will also allow counting of the frequency of appearance certain words in the file. Stored the words in dictionary format such as below:

```
Counter({('mov', 'mov', 'mov'): 18, ('xor', 'mov', 'mov'): 6, ('mov', 'mov', 'pop'): 3, ('mov', 'mov', 'push'): 3, ('pop', 'mov', 'mov'): 3, ('mov', 'call', 'cmp'): 3, ('push', 'pop', 'mov'): 3, ('mov', 'add', 'mov'): 3, ('call', 'mov', 'call'): 3, ('mov', 'mov', 'xor'): 3, ('cmp', 'mov', 'cmp'): 2, ('pop', 'mov', 'add'): 2, ('mov', 'pop', 'mov'): 2, ('mov', 'cmp', 'sub'): 2, ('mov', 'mov', 'sub'): 2, ('mov', 'mov', 'call'): 2})
```

With this dictionary above, I would like to take the values (frequency of appearance) and use in the loglikelihood formula below. My question is how can I modify the code so that it can take in the value from any dictionary like the one above and use it with the codes below. The final result should return numbers and plot a graph using matplotlib.

```
import math
# The placeholder value for 0 counts
epsilon = 0.0001
def opcode_llr(opcode, freq_table_before, freq_table_after):

'''
Args:
    opcode: A single opcode mnemonic, e.g., 'mov'

    freq_table_before: The frequency table for opcode trigrams *before*
                       extraction.

    freq_table_after: The frequency table for opcode trigrams *after*
                      extraction.

The keys for both tables are tuples of string. So, each is of the form

    {
        ('mov', 'mov', 'mov'): 5.0,
        ('mov', 'jmp', 'mov'): 7.0,
        ...
    }

'''
    t_b = len(freq_table_before) or epsilon
    t_a = len(freq_table_after) or epsilon

    # Compute the opcode counts when occurring in positions 0, 1, 2
    opcode_counts = [epsilon, epsilon, epsilon]
    for triplet in freq_table_after.keys():
        for i, comp in enumerate(triplet):
            if comp == opcode:
                opcode_counts[i] += 1

    f1 = opcode_counts[0]
    f2 = opcode_counts[1]
    f3 = opcode_counts[2]

    return (f1 + f2 + f3) * math.log(float(t_b) / t_a)
```

Comment: It is not clear at all what your code is supposed to do. What are the two `freq_table_*` parameters ? How do you pass the `Counter` to your functions. Also please indent the `def` properly, please.

Comment: Please also clarify whether your input is a dictionary or a counter.

Comment: Thanks @wap26 for the guide and I added some other codes and made some changes to my question. As for your query on the two `freq_table_*`  parameters I think its easier to understand with an example. I've written out the logic in a pdf. It can be downloaded using this [link](https://app.box.com/s/rwt2kbusda4vp5izt98izwzpuv39r30l)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic way to compute LLRs from a `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
import random
import math

def CntToLLR(cnt):
    n = sum(cnt.values())   # total number of samples
    LLR = {}                # dict to store LLRs (same keys as counter)
    for x,y in cnt.items(): # x is the key, and y the count
        LLR[x] = math.log(y) - math.log(n - y)
    return LLR

# populate a counter with random values
cnt = Counter([random.randrange(10) for x in range(100)])

llrs = CntToLLR(cnt)

# You can convert the dictionary to a list of (key, value)
llrs = list(llrs.iteritems())
```

Comment: This generates lots of value in dictionary format. If I want to use the output like the ones in the question what should I do and how do I plot them in a graph using matplotlib?

Comment: @zuma, frankly I do not know matplotlib. I intended to answer regarding LLR computation.